# Asslign a value to an LLVM array

Tags: llvm

If I create an LLVM array as

```
%a = alloca [3 x i32]
```

and want to assign a value to the first element in the array, how do I do that?
Do I have to recreate the array with that value in place somehow? I want to use pure LLVM code and not the LLVM API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to get the pointer to the first element using the [`getelementptr`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#i-getelementptr) instruction, which you then use to store your value:

```
%p = getelementptr [3 x i32], [3 x i32]* %a, i32 0, i32 0
store i32 4, i32* %p
```

This stores the value `4` in the first element. To store in a different index, you change the last integer to the index you need:

```
%p = getelementptr [3 x i32], [3 x i32]* %a, i32 0, i32 2
store i32 4, i32* %p
```

This one stores `4` in index `2`.